# XPath: Choosing elements without a class attribute

Tags: r, xml, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract text with the following structure:

```
<p class="id1"> Title or something </p>    
<p> Text text text </p>
<p> More text </p>
<p class="id2"> Something else </p>
```

When I use:

```
text_info <- xpathSApply(PARSED, "//p", xmlValue)
```

The result is:

```
[1] 'Title or something'
[2] 'Text text text'
[3] 'More text'
[4] 'Something else'
```

I want only the text inside `<p>` with no class:

```
[1] 'Text text text'
[2] 'More text'
```

I'm using the following code but it takes a long time and I have many texts:

```
text_info <- setdiff(xpathSApply(PARSED, "//p", xmlValue), xpathSApply(PARSED, "//p[@class]", xmlValue))
```

Is there a way to extract only those who have no class using just one xpathSApply?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `not()` in your XPath.

```
xpathSApply(doc, "//p[not(@class)]", xmlValue, trim = TRUE)
# [1] "Text text text" "More text"
```

This chooses the elements **without** a class attribute.

**Data:**

```
library(XML)
doc <- htmlParse('<p class="id1"> Title or something </p>    
<p> Text text text </p>
<p> More text </p>
<p class="id2"> Something else </p>')
```

Comment: a very _classy_ answer Rich ;-) I'm sure it'll become a _class_ ic